# Why doesn't the "official" json checker allow top-level primitives?

Tags: json, parsing

Among the implementations listed at [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) I stumbled upon [JSON_checker](http://www.json.org/JSON_checker/).

It's copyrighted by JSON.org (which is why I call it "official") and it seems to be very up-to-date: `2016-10-24` is stamped at the top of [`JSON_checker.c`](http://www.json.org/JSON_checker/JSON_checker.c).

However, I noticed that state transition table (line 143 in [`JSON_checker.c`](http://www.json.org/JSON_checker/JSON_checker.c)) defines the starting state (called `GO`) such that it only allow:

- Whitespace
- Start of an object (`{`)
- Start of an array (`[`)

What about the other "primitive" value types: String, Number, Boolean, Null?

There is indeed a state (called `VA` for value) that do allow these primitives as well as Objects and Arrays. But why isn't that the initial starting state?

For example; a simple JSON document containing just:

```
null
```

Is not considered valid according to the JSON_checker.

It is apparent that this is by design; the first test (`fail1.json`) in the test suite clearly states that:

```
"A JSON payload should be an object or array, not a string."
```

Why is this so? My previous experience with JSON is that any JSON value is allowed at the top level.

Comment: Because...Crockford. Just about everyone else is happy with any kind of top-level value, and that's what [was standardized](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-404.htm).

Comment: Ok, that's very... confusing. Nevertheless, your comment answer my question. Post it as an answer so that I can accept it.